# How to correctly write a range of currency?

Tags: american-english, money

Currency is usually written with the type prefixed, e.g. $52.

However, what is the correct way to write a currency range? For example, the inclusive range of 'between 14 and 90 dollars' could be written as:

1. $14-90
2. $14-$90
3. 14-90$

Comment: Would like to see further explanation of why #2 is the best choice, and why #3 is the worst choice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put the currency sign in both places:

> $14–$90

especially because the other two risk confusing the dash with a decimal marker ($14.90).

Comment: And do note the [en dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash), which is not the same as a [hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen).